# Type declaration using reals in ACSL/Frama-C

Tags: c, frama-c

I have some issues with ACSL specification for the last Frama-C version.
I tried a lot of things to declare a pair of reals, but none of them worked.
Here is a tiny example illustrating by problem :

```
/*@ type real_pair = (real, real); */
```

Which gives :

> [kernel] user error: unexpected token '('

At the end, I want to have a code near to :

```
/*@ axiomatic RealPairs { 

type real_pair = (real, real);  

logic real Norm ( real_pair p ) =   
\let (x,y) = p;  
\sqrt(x*x + y*y);  

} */
```

Does someone see where the error is ? I found the ACSL documentation very vague on the type declarations...

Thank you very much for your answers.

Best regards,

Nilexys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have written is correct with respect to the ACSL manual. However, as you can see in the ACSL **Implementation** manual
(http://frama-c.com/download/frama-c-acsl-implementation.pdf), pairs are not supported in the current implementation of ACSL in Frama-C. In fact, the only thing that is partially supported in this area of ACSL is sum types. More precisely, you can define sum types, but the `\match` construction is not supported by Frama-C, which means that you have to resort to axiomatics. In the current state of affairs, the following should be accepted by Frama-C (not tested though):

```
/*@ type real_pair = RPCons(real, real); */
/*@ axiomatic Real_pair {
     logic real rp_fst(real_pair p);
     logic real rp_snd(real_pair p);
     axiom rp_fst_def: \forall real x, y; rp_fst(RPCons(x,y)) == x;
     axiom rp_snd_def: \forall real x,y; rp_snd(RPCons(x,y)) == y;
 */
```